# How to use RewriteRule within .htaccess on xampplite?

Tags: apache-2.2, php, .htaccess, xampp

I am using [.htaccess file to enable url rewrite](http://corz.org/serv/tricks/htaccess2.php).

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on
DirectorySlash off 
Options -Indexes
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index\.php [NC]
```

It works as it should on the production php server.

It does not however work with out of the box **xampplite**.

How do I fix it? How do i debug it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does anything in .htaccess file apply actually? You need to enable processing of this file, see [`AllowOverride`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/core.html#allowoverride) directive.

Comment: The fix:

RewriteBase /some-dir/ 

http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum40/117-1-15.htm